# Day and month names ignore certain formats in date filter and revert to number

Tags: datetime, filter, language

When I try to output the day name (l or D) or month name (F or M) i get a number instead of the day/month-name.

```
{{ entry.end|date("j. F Y") }}
```

turns into:

```
1. 9 2015
```

when output.

Expected output would be `1. oktober 2015` (site language is Norwegian (nb)) or even `1. October 2015` (if internationalization did not work).

Comment: I'd try and reinstall the craft/app/ folder, looks like there's some files missing / corrupted.

Comment: I'm actually seeing the exact same behavior for all 3 Norwegian locales (no, nn and nb). Other locales – such as Swedish – work as expected, though. Smells like a bug? Ran my test on a fresh d/l.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest version of Craft specific to Norwegian locales that will be fixed in the next (post [2.3.2643](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2643)) release.

Comment: Patch now available w/ [build 2644](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2644).